# How to define spinner by id and not by position

Tags: java, android

**[Menu screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8Ot.jpg)**

**The menu is not selecting the correct position of the registered category id**

I am making a app of restaurant.

I have a spinner populate by category list.
When I go select a product I want to pull all informations of product, how name and category.

The problem is that I dont get to select category by id registered.

Example, I have these positions and these ids:
0 - 3(id)
1 - 2(id)
2 - 15(id)
3 - 10(id)

**My menu is saved in the database, when I choose the menu I want to show on the screen its information, such as menu name, ingredients and its category. To search for the category I'm looking for the id_category.**

**I want that when I open the menu, the spinner is automatically filled in by the position of the id_category**

```
    private CategoriaNovo spinnerCategoria;
    private List<CategoriaNovo> listaCategorias = new ArrayList<>();
```

My Spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<CategoriaNovo> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CategoriaNovo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaCategorias);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

How am I listing the data in the spinner

```
JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_listar_categoria, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                            CategoriaNovo categoria = new CategoriaNovo();
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                categoria.setIdCategoria(jsonObject.getInt("idCategoria"));
                                categoria.setCategoria(jsonObject.getString("nomeCategoria"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Erro 01",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            listaCategorias.add(categoria);
                        }
                        carregarSpinner();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Erro 02",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
```

Comment: Whst does it mean `How do I get the position of id 15?`?

Comment: it needs more clarification, not getting what actually you want

Comment: My menu is saved in the database, when I choose the menu I want to show on the screen its information, such as menu name, ingredients and its category.
To search for the category I'm looking for the id_category.